# Html.BeginRouteForm иногда вызывает Get запрос, вместо Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor

Добавил форму для загрузки файла через Html.BeginRouteForm, в большинстве случаев все работает как нужно, но иногда, при нажатии на `<input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />`, вызывается Get запрос, вместо Post. На форме явно указан FormMethod.Post. С чем может это быть связано? Заранее спасибо!

На проекте используется Net Framework

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane @(promoLoadAction ? "active" : "")" id="load">
    @if (promoLoadAction) {
        <p>@promoLoadResultMessage</p>
    }
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("company.one.manage.load", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
    }
    Названия колонок и формат данных:<br />
    <b>UserId</b> (число, например, 1)<br />
    <b>Promocode</b> (строка, например, Promocode) <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Никогда не сталкивался с похожим поведением. А вы это при локальном запуске обнаруживаете или на проде? А то может у вас посередине между клиентом и сервером [находится какой-нибудь модификатор запросов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37908024/) - там Lavarel с rewrite-правилами, а у вас допустим nginx. Вторая мысль - что у вас порядок аргументов перепутался для BeginRouteForm и стоит внимательно посмотреть на [порядок аргументов, что куда передаётся](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4596135/). Сам не могу сказать правильный порядок, давно не писал формы и нет под рукой проекта, а перегрузок там много

Comment: @AK ловлю локально. Ловится примерно так, я загрузил один файл и на этой же странице пытаюсь загрузить еще один. В 4/5 случаях все ок, в 1 вызывается get.

Параметры точно не перепутаны:
```public static MvcForm BeginRouteForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string routeName, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes);```

Comment: Вряд ли локально у вас что-то такое стоит. Хм, не знаю, у меня лично гипотезы кончились. PS А если всё же заменить routeName на контроллер-экшн вариант? Так чисто, на шару - вдруг при таких условиях что-то поменяется и ошибка перестанет воспроизводиться?

Comment: @AK к сожалению не как, на проекте используется модифицированный MVC, все действия используются через routeName

Comment: У метода, принимающего файл, установлен атрибут [HttpPost]?

Comment: @Neomaster да, атрибут установлен